# MySQL - Classic Date Functions

Tags: mysql, mariadb, date, mariadb-10.2

Version: 10.2.18-MariaDB

I'm attempting to find the first available room within December (already included in the sample table) that will be free for 3 consecutive days.

The expected output should be:

```
Room 201, 2016-12-11
```

My question is essentially more about the syntax of SQL, should I be using the DATEDIFF function to determine the booking end date, or is there another method which I am not thinking of?

```
+--------------+--------+---------+--------------+
| booking_date | nights | room_no | arrival_time |
+--------------+--------+---------+--------------+
| 2016-12-01   |      2 |     201 | 17:00        |
| 2016-12-02   |      2 |     301 | 20:00        |
| 2016-12-03   |      5 |     101 | 16:00        |
| 2016-12-03   |      4 |     201 | 18:00        |
| 2016-12-04   |      1 |     301 | 15:00        |
| 2016-12-05   |      5 |     301 | 14:00        |
| 2016-12-07   |      4 |     201 | 20:00        |
| 2016-12-08   |      2 |     101 | 18:00        |
| 2016-12-10   |      5 |     101 | 23:00        |
| 2016-12-12   |      1 |     301 | 12:00        |
| 2016-12-15   |      3 |     101 | 19:00        |
+--------------+--------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: added the version @Akina

Comment: Well, your version knows about window functions and CTE. So you can prepare your data there. Build from-till pairs for each range when room is free (using LEAD function), then filter by the length you need. PS. I don't understand the correlation between your task and output fields in your query. **PPS.** Your query referres to `room_type_requested` field not shown in source data...

Comment: @Akina I'm not familiar with SQL so that doesn't make an awful lot of sense. What don't you understand about the output and task? That is the next available date and room number, I just don't know how to achieve this through SQL. `room_type_requested` doesn't have any reference to my question.

Comment: *What don't you understand about the output and task?* You search for free range. So you do NOT need in all fields you select except `room_no`... in contrary you NEED in range start data, but you do not obtain it.

Answer (score 1):

Test:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT room_no, 
       booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY d_start, 
       DATEDIFF(COALESCE(LEAD(booking_date) OVER (PARTITION BY room_no ORDER BY booking_date), 
                         '2100-01-01'), 
                booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY) d_free
FROM booking
)
SELECT room_no, d_start
FROM cte
WHERE d_free >= 3
ORDER BY 2;
```

Output on test data is:

```
room_no d_start
201     2016-12-11
301     2016-12-13
101     2016-12-18
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=187e49736bedfc26c671346c42bd1bbb)

Comment: This creates an error "booking.booking_date is not in GROUP BY." I appreciate the help however this seems to be over complicating the issue, is there not a more obvious solution or DATE function?

Comment: *This creates an error "booking.booking_date is not in GROUP BY."* Fiddle (MariaDB-10.2.17) shows the query is correct. Search the problem in another point.

Comment: I'm on version 10.2.18 if that matters.

Comment: This versions have no differences which may affect on this query.